# DynamoDB search using partition key and index

Tags: pyspark, hive, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-emr

I have not seen examples of DynamoDB search using a **partition key** and an **index** (python, boto way).  Would it be possible to direct to any links/examples?

Comment: I recommend splitting these two questions into two actual posts.

Comment: @Kirk sure will do

Answer (score 0):

```
#import Key, Attr
#dynamodb=boto3.resource(....)
#table = dynamodb.resource('tablename')...
#usual stuff commented above

response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('hash_key').eq(hash_value),
    FilterExpression = Attr('column-name-that-has-an-index-NOT-THE-INDEX-NAME').eq(indexvalue)
)
```